# R ggmap: overlaying Europe outline with relief data (GTOPO30)

Tags: r, ggmap

I'm facing a problem overlaying the European outline with relief data from the European Environment Agency.

I found a valuable source to represent data from Europe on ggmap [here](http://www.milanor.net/blog/maps-in-r-choropleth-maps/). The required administration boundaries can be downloaded [here](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/de/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/nuts).
However, instead of overlaying the European outline with Google maps, I want to use a relief of Europe (GTOPO30). I found the according data [here](https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/digital-elevation-model-of-europe).

However, I'm unable to combine the two graphs. I guess the problem is within the different coordination systems:

Administration boundaries example:
long lat
16.56577 47.63857
Relief example:
value     x     y
38 124.5 196.5

The corresponding graph looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBdNl.png).

Any help is highly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(raster)
library(dplyr)

setwd("your working directory")

# read in background relief
relief <- raster("elevation9x9/elevation9x9.tif")
relief_spdf <- as(relief, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
relief <- as.data.frame(relief_spdf) %>% 
  rename(value = `elevation9x9`)

# read administrative boundaries
eurMap <- readShapePoly(fn="NUTS_2010_60M_SH/data/NUTS_RG_60M_2010.shp")
eurMapDf <- fortify(eurMap[eurMap$STAT_LEVL_==0,],region="NUTS_ID")

# read downloaded data
eurEdu <- read.csv("educ_thexp_1_Data.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
eurEdu$Value <- as.double(eurEdu$Value) #format as numeric

# merge map and data
eurEduMapDf <- merge(eurMapDf, eurEdu, by.x="id", by.y="GEO")
eurEduMapDf <- eurEduMapDf[order(eurEduMapDf$order),]

#limit data to main Europe
lon <- c(54.78333,24.08464,-31.26192,59.34569)
lat <- c(80.56667,34.83469,39.45479,62.21215)
europe.limits = data.frame(lon,lat)

eurEduMapDf <- subset(eurEduMapDf, long > min(europe.limits$lon) & long < max(europe.limits$lon) & lat > min(europe.limits$lat) & lat < max(europe.limits$lat))

p <-    ggplot() +
        geom_raster(data = relief, aes(x = x, y = y, alpha = value)) +
        geom_polygon(data=eurEduMapDf, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=Value)) + coord_equal() +
        geom_path(data=eurEduMapDf, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color='white')
```

Comment: For the two data sets to be merged, they must use the same coordinate system. One of your sets is using geographic coordinates, the other seemingly pixel coordinates (that's what your image shows). You have to perform a coordinate transformation.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I was heading in the same direction with the proj4 package but was unable to do the transformation. Do you have an idea how to do the transformation?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know r nor any of its packages, so I don't exactly understand what's going on in your code. If it is what I expect though, you don't even need proj4, since it's just a display scaling issue. So you need to multiply all your WGS points with a x/y scale value and a shift.

Comment: Thank you PMF. I give it a try. If anyone else has a good idea I'm more than happy about it.